# Spring - autowired fields are null

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, autowired

I faced a problem with Spring Framework: `@Autowired` are null, but Spring doesn't throw any exceptions, and I can't understand, why are these fields null.

I have a class:

```
package com.processing.gates;

public class Main {

    private final ApplicationContext context = Context.getContext();

    @Autowired private PaymentGateFactory paymentGateFactory;
    @Autowired private CalculatorChooser calculatorChooser;

    //...
}
```

And for example I have the following class:

```
package com.processing.gates.comission;

@Component
public class CalculatorChooser {
    //...
}
```

Here is my Spring configuration xml:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.processing.gates"/>


    <bean id="logPath" class="java.lang.String"> <!-- путь к папке с логами -->
        <constructor-arg value="/home/yoba/NetBeansProjects/processing/gates/log/"/>
    </bean>
    <!-- ... -->
</beans>
```

When I try to write in xml:

`<bean id="calculator" class="com.processing.gates.comission.CalculatorChooser"/>`

and get it from code:

```
CalculatorChooser cc = (CalculatorChooser)Context.getContext().getBean("calculator");
```

it works fine. But @Autowired doesn't work. How can I fix this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let Spring manage the bean by either declaring a `Main` bean in the application context file or by using the `@Component` annotation as you've already done for `CalculatorChooser`

```
<bean id="mainBean" class="com.processing.gates.Main"/>
```

Comment: Thanks, it helped! So Spring can autowire fields only in beans?

Comment: Well yeah @gth99. If spring isn't aware of a class, it has no reason to go snooping in it